# how to select all items at a time when cliking on select all menuitem  for a listfield checkbox in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, listfield

I want to select all items in a listfield at a time when cliking on the select all menu item in the application.i tried with my code like this..

```
selectall = new MenuItem("Selectall", 200, 10){
            public void run(){
            int elementLength = _elements.length;
             for(int count = 0; count < elementLength; ++count)
                {
            _listData.addElement(new ChecklistData(_elements[count], true));
            listField.insert(count);
                }
            }
        };
```

but iam getting the result with old list also.below the old list this new list is coming with checked.how to solve that.please give your ideas.and where iam doing the mistake.thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your all suggestions. i solved my problem now..the solution is..

```
selectall = new MenuItem("Selectall", 200, 10){
            public void run(){

                int elementLength = _elements.length;
                for(int count = 0; count < elementLength; ++count)
                {
                    _listData.setElementAt(new ChecklistData(_elements[count], true), count);

                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Your method will work, but you are also wasting memory. You are creating a second copy of that `ChecklistData` items just to set the checkbox value to be checked. Yes, Java's Garbage Collector will clean it up, but you're creating extra work for the phone and your app over something that is very simple to do. I still say you need to find a away to set the ChecklistData's check box to be checked, without creating a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `listField.insert` means that you're adding new `ChecklistData` objects to the list. That's why you're getting a completely new list underneath your previous one. Instead of adding to `_listData`, go through it and set the `ChecklistData` to be checked.

It looks like that is a custom class, so I don't know what it will take for you to do that. If you used [`CheckboxField`s](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/CheckboxField.html) in `_listData`, you could do it like this:

```
for (Enumeration e = _listdata.elements() ; e.hasMoreElements() ;) {
    CheckboxField c = (CheckboxField)e.nextElement();
    c.setChecked(true);
}
```

Comment: i tried with your code.but iam getting the exception like this Exception is:java.lang.ClassCastException.the result is not changed just list elements are same as before.i didn't set to true.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer.i got the solution.i tried like this.. _listData.setElementAt(new ChecklistData(_elements[count], true), count); now its working correctly for me.